# I separated my _type column while creating procedure but it's results are not true in MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `user_factors`(in users_id int)
begin
select u.id,count(f._type in (select f._type from factor as f where f._type=1)) as payed ,
 count(f._type in (select f._type from factor as f where f._type !=1)) as unpayed , count(f.id) as factor_count
from users as u
end
```

[It says that we have two _type s 1 & 3 so when we call it we have to see one payed and one not [but in second picture we see that it's filled both with 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2jr1.png) payed][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5Hyc.png)

Comment: your question is not clear .. try add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  .. (as tabular text not image) .. add  try explain better the relation (if any) between user and my_type

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your data  saple seems you are looking for a conditional aggregation for the joined  table limited to your_user_id

```
select u.id
,sum( case when f._type f._type=1 THEN 1 else 0 end ) as payed 
,sum( case when f._type f._type!=1 THEN 1 else 0 end ) as unpayed 
, count(f.id) as factor_count
from users as u
INNER FACTOR f ON u.id = f.user_id
WHERE u.id = your_user_id


select u.id
,sum( case when f._type f._type=1 THEN 1 else 0 end ) as payed 
,sum( case when f._type f._type!=1 THEN 1 else 0 end ) as unpayed 
, count(f.id) as factor_count
from users as u
INNER FACTOR f ON u.id = f.user_id
WHERE u.id = 4585
```